# problem while getting key value for url to data , then to uiimage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a URL with tag:

http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/sunny.gif

When I do like this:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/sunny.gif"];
```

it's getting image in gdb and I am able to download from this URL. But when I write code like this:

```
NSURL *url=[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"];
```

(where `jsonItem` is dictionary  and passing it to data and then to `UIImage`), then it shows an exception.

When I get the value of:

```
  [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"];
```

in gdb then it shows like:

```
2011-03-15 11:08:16.405 XML[1576:20b] jsonURKL  ..... ...

http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/thunderstorms.gif   (in next line in gdb)
```

I need to download through this:

```
NSURL *url=[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"];
```

I am not able to do that. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the `jsonItem` dictionary? If not, can you `NSLog` the value of `[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]`? We need some more clues as to what class it is, etc.

Comment: 2011-03-15 11:34:28.383 XML[1709:20b] value  ..... ...
         http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/partlycloudy.gif

Comment: but i have doubt that the value of url that i am geting in gdb is in next line...

Answer (score 2):

Url itself one string.
so you have to use below code

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
```

now setimgge with `[UIImage imageWithData: data];` this code

Comment: the value showing null value!! i guess !! the problem is of space or next line that contain in my xml tag,,,

Comment: 2011-03-15 12:20:33.597 XML[2068:20b] jsonItem....{
    PictureURL = "\n       http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/sunny.gif";
}

Comment: i have doubt on "\n".. might be i am not getting the value in nsdata.

Comment: this xml file is not on my local host i am fetching it from web!

Comment: nsstring *tempstr=[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"];
 tempstr=[tempstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"Http://"];

now u can edit this string

Comment: thanks!! now its working!! i have done like this: NSString *tempstr=[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]; 
 tempstr=[tempstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n    h" withString:@"h"];

Answer (score 1):

please do this in following way,

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
cell.iconImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

Comment: [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"] contain only url, so i cannot use        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]];   instead i am using NSURL *url=[jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"];

Comment: its not the problem!! i guess!! but the problem is when i get the value of     [jsonItem objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]; then it shows the url in next line.. is it matter or  any kind of issue ??

Comment: i think..this is the right way...otherwise its a problem of yar parsing or on yar server side...if u trace it... let me know..

Comment: does any body know how to get url without spaces or any other character in nsurl?